# Upload File After Save to Network Share Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ftp, visual-studio-extensions

I started using VS 2015 for Javascript code development, after using WebStorm. WebStorm can be configured to deploy or upload a file directly to a share/ftp when a file is saved. Is there such option in VS for this?